# Edit comments from an XML file

Tags: xml

Is there a way to edit an XML file from the macOS terminal as to uncomment and line which is currently behind a comment? I've tried an XSLT file and a sed command and neither worked.

Comment: Tell us what you've tried. Best would be a _Minimal, Complete, Verifyable Example_. With XSLT, even version 1.0, this should be doable.

Comment: `<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="comment()"/>
    <xsl:template match="@choice">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(.,'&#x9;')"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="question|answer">
        <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>`

Comment: I had to leave out the XSLT declaration due to post character limits.

Here's the sed command: sed '/<!--/,/-->/d' file.xml

Thanks!

Comment: Well, my edit to include your XSLT code into your question was rejected, so you have to do it yourself. I created an answer in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

To remove comments and include their content in the resulting XML, simply change this template in your XSLT

```
<xsl:template match="comment()" />
```

to

```
<xsl:template match="comment()">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

This will include all of the content of the comments in your result XML.